# Moving Mouth animation

Tags: android, image, animation

I am working on application similar to talking Tom. I am struggling over the feature of providing talking effect to an image from camera. Recording and playing audio is already done.
We can not use gif as we have images from Camera.

Can anyone help me out in How can i make a similar talking animation?
Many thankfull if anyone even provide some idea to me .

Comment: Your best bet would be having a generic animated 3D character and then map the face taken by the camera onto it... But I have no clue on how to do that. Maybe with OpenGL or libgdx?

Answer (score -1):

you can take multiple images of mouth in a sequence and with the help of thread(uiThread) change the image, sequentially.